# How do I translate this google sheet data structure into an object?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am looking to convert a set of data in this format into an object that I can use to help update google form choices. However, I am stumped.

As per a comment below, I would like to add some clarity. The values in row 1 define a year group and until another number appears in row 1, all columns belong to that year group.

However, the only data that needs to be returned for each day (row 2) is the column that contains 'Form Display'.

Columns containing 'capacity' and '#registered' are to be ignored and there may be some values underneath those letters.

Here is the google sheet.

[image]

I would like this to be converted into an object as follows:

```
[
  {'Year group': Year 5,
   'Sunday': ['Girls football', 'Mixed Gaelic football', 'Science experiments', 'library club'...],
   'Monday': ['Boys football','Netball],
   'Wednesday': ['Taekwondo', 'School choir', 'Mixed basketball', 'Lego', 'Board games']
},
{'Year group': Year 6,
   'Sunday': ['Girls football', 'mixed gaelic football', 'science experiments', 'library club'...],
},
```

Thank you!

Comment: I think you need to be more specific.  For example, i believe the values in row 1 define a year group.  And until another number appears in row 1 those columns belong to a year group.  I don't have any idea what the b,c,d, refer to on row 2 and if there will be values there or only d.

Comment: @TheWizEd, thank you for your comment. I have replaced the picture to give clarity and also given more clarity to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a protype of a script that will create an object from the data set shown in the OP.

I am basically using the row 1 `yearLabels` to determine the year group and row 2 `dayLabels` to determine the day and simply walking through each column to see what the "header" is.  If there is extraneous data beyond the last year group I didn't test for errors.  In my look ahead `if( dayLabels[column+1] )` I'm looking to see if it is `undefined`.

```
function testObject() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("TestData");
    let values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    let yearGroups = [];
    let yearLabels = values.shift(); // get the first row, year labels
    let dayLabels = values.shift(); // get the second row, day labels
    let yearGroup = null;
    let day = null;
    yearLabels.forEach( (label,column) => {
        if( label !== "" ) {
          if( yearGroup ) yearGroups.push(yearGroup);
          yearGroup = { "Year group": label };
          day = dayLabels[column];
          yearGroup[day] = [];
        }
        else if( dayLabels[column] === "Form Display") {
          values.some( row => {
              if( row[column] !== "" ) {
                yearGroup[day].push(row[column]);
                return false;
              }
              else {
                return true;
              }
            }
          );
          // look ahead to see if there is another day
          if( dayLabels[column+1] ) {
            if( yearLabels[column+1] === "" ) {
              day = dayLabels[column+1];
              yearGroup[day] = [];
            }
          }
        }
      }
    );
    // need to store the last yearGroup
    yearGroups.push(yearGroup);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(yearGroups));
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Execution log

```
6:51:02 AM  Notice  Execution started
6:51:04 AM  Info    [{"Year group":"Year 5","Sunday":["Girls Football","Mixed Gaelic Football","Science Experiments","Library Club","Rapid Maths"],"Tuesday":["Boys Football","Netball"],"Wednesday":["Taekwondo","Shool Choir","Mixed Basketball","Lego","Board Games"]},{"Year group":"Year 6","Sunday":["Girls Football","Mixed Gaelic Football","Science Experiments","Library Club","Newspaper Club/Reading Club","Rapid Maths"]}]
6:51:03 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

References

- [Array.shift()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_shift.asp)
- [Array.forEach()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp)
- [Array.some()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_some.asp)

Comment: thank you very much. This is exactly what I wished for.